# SwiftUI @State not updated in older project

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to add a simple SwiftUI view to an existing project, but `@State` changes are not propagated properly. The code works as expected in a new project, but doesn't work in the older project. The same thing happens with `@ObservedObject`.

Code:

```
struct ChannelAccountsView: View {

    @State private var showGreeting = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $showGreeting) {
                Text("Show welcome message")
            }.padding()

            if showGreeting {
                Text("Hello World!")
            }
        }
    }
}

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            let contentView = ChannelAccountsView()
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
...
}
```

New project:

[image]

Old project:

[image]

Tried all of the obvious fixes:

- Edited AppDelegate and added SceneDelegate
- Edited Info.plist
- Cleaned Project and the Derived data
- Reset simulator data
- Tested on multiple simulators/devices

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: What do you mean by `older project` and how it differs from `new project`?

Comment: @Asperi `older project ` -> project that existed for 2+ years and previously didn't use SwiftUI
`new project` -> newly created project that had SwiftUI selected as the UI creation option

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and the root cause was that my target had the `Reflection Metadata Level` set to `None` under `Swift Compiler - General` category inside Build Settings.

Changing it to `All` fixed it for me:

[image: Reflection Metadata Level]

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new Target within the Project resolved the issues. Still not sure what the root cause is.